# VB 2013 Project References Tab Not Enabled

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have added a SQL Server database to my Visual Basic 2013 project.

`DBNAMEDataSet.xsd` appears under the project listing in the Solution Explorer.

Attempting to build sql for a new view in `dbo.{ViewName}.sql` code window.

Clicking on "Update" results in error message

```
SQL71501 :: Table: [DBName].[DBTableName] has an unresolved reference to Schema [DBName].
```

Project References list (in Project Properties, References tab) shows `System.Data`, but no reference to the connected Database (DBName). 
The References tab of the Project Properties window is not enabled, so adding a reference by using the Add button of that tab is not possible.

Comment: That is not talking about project references to assemblies.  It's talking about the SQL code specifying a schema that doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: jmcilhinney, thank you for that insight. But I'm still confused.
Here is the SQL:
CREATE VIEW [BLOSSOM].[ListNames]
AS SELECT TOP (1) * FROM Client ORDER BY LastName

Here are error messages generated on Update:
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name BLOSSOM.ListNames.FirstName.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name BLOSSOM.ListNames.LastName.
 ...I don't understand the "The model already has an element  ..." messages. I'm adding the ListNames view, so how can there already be an element that has the name BLOSSOM.ListNames{.anything}?

Comment: Have you searched the web for information on that error code?